# Getting error cant sent header after they are sent usning express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am getting expected response after all the process but it fails at the with error `cant set header after they are sent`

main.ts

```
export class GetAccountBalanceController extends Controller {
    public static async process(@Request() request: ExpressRequest,
                                response: ExpressResponse): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const instance = new GetAccountBalanceController();
            const data = await instance.execute(request, response);
            response.status(200);
            response.send(data);
        } catch (err) {
            response.status(200);
            response.send(err.message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: response.status(200).send(data)

Comment: @Deda and same for err response ?

Comment: yes, and I would suggest you to use different status, 400 for best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to append the "send" with the status and it should clear it up for you! Also I changed the status to a 400 in the catch :) Hope this helps!

```
        try {
            const instance = new GetAccountBalanceController();
            const data = await instance.execute(request, response);
            response.status(200).send(data);
        } catch (err) {
            response.status(400).send(err.message);
        }
```

Comment: EDIT: I didn't look in the comments before posting my answer and it looks like it was answered already in the exact way I put here. If you want me to delete the answer, I can since it was technically already answered haha