# Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm using nodejs, express, and argon2. I'm running into this error and I'm not sure why. I don't have any callbacks so I'm confused on why I'm getting this error. Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const argon2 = require("argon2themax");

app.use(express.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

// dumby
global.user = [{username:"u1", password:"hidden", email:"email@gmail.com"}];

// signin routes
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {

  //console.log(req.body);

  // validate the json
  if(req.body.username === undefined || req.body.password === undefined) {
    res.status(500);
    res.render('error', { error: err });
  } else {
    try {

      // let argon2 generate our salt
      argon2.generateSalt()
      .then(function(salt) {

          // Hashing happens in an asynchronous event using libuv so your system can
          // still process other IO items in the Node.JS queue, such as web requests.
          return argon2.hash(req.body.password, salt, maxOpts);

      }).then(function(hash) {

          // This hash is what you should store in your database. Treat it as an opaque string.
          global.user.push({username:req.body.username, password:hash});

          // Verifying the hash against your user's password is simple.
          res.json(true);
      })
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Unexpected error: " + error);
      //res.status(500);
      //res.render('error', { error: err });
    }
  }
})

app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {

  var success = false;

  global.user.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    if(item.username == req.body.username) {
      try {
        argon2.verify(item.password, req.body.password).then(function(match) {
              if(match) {
                console.log("pword match");
                res.json(true);
              } else {
                res.json(false);
              }
              console.log("done");
          });
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("no uname");
      res.json(false);
    }
  });

})
```

My server will throw this error only when I hit my /signup route before the /signin route. I believe this is an asynchronous problem but I'm not sure how to solve it. The full error message reads:

```
(node:21623) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/[redacted]/Public/Docs/[redacted]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:775:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/[redacted]/Public/Docs/[redacted]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/[redacted]/Public/Docs/[redacted]/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:271:15)
    at /Users/[redacted]/Public/Docs/[redacted]/server.js:106:17
(node:21623) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:21623) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: It usually means that you're calling `res.status` twice in the same code-path.

Comment: I don't call res.status at all. I'm guessing it's something in express that's calling res.status but I'm not sure how or where

Comment: After putting in debug statements I've figured out that it's an asynchronous problem. The thread exits the /signin handler and while it waits on argon2.verify() to finish and then comes back into that branch. How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error cant sent header after they are sent usning express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744992/getting-error-cant-sent-header-after-they-are-sent-usning-express)

Comment: @VikashSingh initially I thought so too, but then figured that it's only the symptom. The real issue is described below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both methods, this is not the correct way to implement `catch` for a promise chain:

```
try {

      // let argon2 generate our salt
      argon2.generateSalt()
      .then(function(salt) {

          // Hashing happens in an asynchronous event using libuv so your system can
          // still process other IO items in the Node.JS queue, such as web requests.
          return argon2.hash(req.body.password, salt, maxOpts);

      }).then(function(hash) {

          // This hash is what you should store in your database. Treat it as an opaque string.
          global.user.push({username:req.body.username, password:hash});

          // Verifying the hash against your user's password is simple.
          res.json(true);
      })
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("Unexpected error: " + error);
      //res.status(500);
      //res.render('error', { error: err });
    }
```

Instead you should do something like:

```
  // let argon2 generate our salt
  argon2.generateSalt()
  .then(function(salt) {

      // Hashing happens in an asynchronous event using libuv so your system can
      // still process other IO items in the Node.JS queue, such as web requests.
      return argon2.hash(req.body.password, salt, maxOpts);

  }).then(function(hash) {

      // This hash is what you should store in your database. Treat it as an opaque string.
      global.user.push({username:req.body.username, password:hash});

      // Verifying the hash against your user's password is simple.
      res.json(true);
  }).catch(error => {
       console.log("Unexpected error: " + error);
  });
```

Comment: This didn't fix the problem but what is the difference between .catch() and try-catch?

Comment: I just thought it about it again and I realize this probably would've fixed the issue but I solved it a different way

Comment: @JustinCase in regards your first comment: surrounding the code with try/catch won't help since this code returns an unfulfilled promise so nothing is "thrown" until after the execution exits the try-clause.